# Is there any layout model exists for QGraphicsItem

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qlayout

Unfortunately I can't see any documented information about this.
I need a layout class like `QLayout` but not for widgets in widgets but for `QGraphicsItem` inside `QGraphicsItem`s. I have:

```
class AnotherGraphicsItem : public QGraphicsItem {
public:
    QRectF boundingRect();

    void paint(QPainter *painter, ...) {
        painter->drawRect(0, 0, 30, 30);
        // ...
    }
};

class GraphicsItem : public QGraphicsItem {
public:
    QRectF boundingRect();

    void paint(...) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            AnotherGraphicsItem *aItem = new AnotherGraphicsItem();
            aItem->setPos(i * 20, 0);
            aItem->setParent(this);
        }
    }
};

class GraphicsView : public QGraphicsView {
public:
    GraphicsView(){ setScene(new QGraphicsScene(this)); populate(); }
    void populate() {
        QGraphicsItem *item = new GraphicsItem();
        scene()->addItem(item);
    }
};
```

Briefly, my `GraphicsView` objects have a scene which has QGraphicsItem objects inside another QGraphicsItem objects

> QGraphicsView -> QGraphicsScene -> QGraphicsItem (GraphicsItem) -> 4x QGraphicsItem (AnotherGraphicsItem)

The problem is that I need `AnotherGraphicsItem` to be aligned somehow in the outer `GraphicsItem` object. I've though to use `QGraphicsLayout` but it seems it needs to be used inside `QGraphicsWidget` which I am not gonna use or it works only in `QGraphicsView` (it has `setLayout()` method).

Some good examples are also welcome.

Comment: I have never tried do this, I have never had to put QGraphicsItem inside other QGraphicsItem, but it really looks like Qt wants you to use a QGraphicsWidget as parent for other items.